# Python Apache beam WriteToText setting max size for part files

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam

I am using WriteToText to Google cloud storage. Files are generated in this format, eg: 1656288022-00009-of-00017.json.gz and there will 17 part files.

Code I wrote to write to our storage path:

```
# extract data is a PCollection of strings

(extract_data
     | 'SaveToGCS' >> beam.io.WriteToText(file_path_prefix=gcs_path, file_name_suffix=".json.gz")
     )
```

Is there a way I can limit the size of the part files generated, some times the file sizes are  growing more than what I need ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only way to do this is to fix the number of shards, which can be expensive (as it incurs a shuffle of all the data). However, I've seen this request come up before, so I filed https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/22129 and hopefully this capability should be available in the next release of Beam.